# Is there a way to prevent formatting of else { trivial expression }

Tags: rust, rustfmt

I often have code like

```
    if condition {
             // code that deserves to 
             // be formatted as block
    }
    else { None }   // or some other trivial expression
```

Now, is there a way to prevent rustfmt from wasting two lines formatting the trivial else part like this:

```
    else {
        None
    }
```

Note that `single_line_if_else_maxwidth` doesn't help, as the "then" part is too long.

Comment: No. That's not the idiomatic format. Denser code is not easier to read. Just go with the “waste” of lines.

Comment: @mcarton then why does single_line_if_else_maxwidth exist? Precisely because **sometimes** dense code **actually is** easier to read.

Comment: @mcarton  Actually, it was shown long ago by researchers (wish I could find a reference!) that fewer lines *are* better inasmuch as a routine that did not fit on one page was considerably more likely to contain an error.  That was on the printed page, but the idea survives that it helps if you can see the whole routine at once.  However, I'm not advocating for the OP's formatting.

Comment: This nightly API would be even more concise, and idiomatic:
`condition.then(|| <code to produce the contents of Some>)`
e.g. `person.is_valid().then(|| person.id)` produces `Some(id)` or `None`.

Comment: @AmigoNico Yes, that looks good. In the meantime, I use match in place of if everywhere.